# Media player start/stop - crash

Tags: android

I want to do that when you press the ImageButton sound is started, and after the next click it is stopped.

Starting and stopping work. But when you press the back button, the program crashes.

Where is the problem?

Code:

```
public class Sound extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        public int count = 0;
        MediaPlayer y;  
        ImageButton th;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app);
        th = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibFirst);
        y = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.th);
        th.setOnClickListener(this);
        count = 0;
    }
    public void onClick(View th) {
        if(count == 0){
            y.start();
            count = 1;
        } else {
            y.pause();                
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(y != null) {
            y.pause();
            y.stop();
            y.release();
            count = 0;
        }
        }


}
```

ERRORS:

When i clicked start/stop start/stop 10x :D

```
3-02 14:21:05.395: W/MediaPlayer(233): info/warning (1, 44)
    03-02 14:21:05.494: I/MediaPlayer(233): Info (1,44)
    03-02 14:22:28.085: E/MediaPlayer(233): pause called in state 128
    03-02 14:22:28.085: E/MediaPlayer(233): error (-38, 0)
    03-02 14:22:28.085: E/MediaPlayer(233): Error (-38,0)
    03-02 14:22:33.455: E/MediaPlayer(233): start called in state 0
    03-02 14:22:33.455: E/MediaPlayer(233): error (-38, 0)
    03-02 14:22:33.455: E/MediaPlayer(233): Error (-38,0)
    03-02 14:22:35.964: W/KeyCharacterMap(233): No keyboard for id 0
    03-02 14:22:35.964: W/KeyCharacterMap(233): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
    03-02 14:22:36.584: E/MediaPlayer(233): pause called in state 0
    03-02 14:22:36.584: E/MediaPlayer(233): error (-38, 0)
    03-02 14:22:36.584: E/MediaPlayer(233): stop called in state 0
    03-02 14:22:36.584: E/MediaPlayer(233): error (-38, 0)
```

When I pressed back button.

```
        03-02 14:22:36.635: D/AndroidRuntime(233): Shutting down VM
        03-02 14:22:36.635: W/dalvikvm(233): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
        03-02 14:22:36.635: E/AndroidRuntime(233): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
        03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.troll.sound/com.troll.sound.Sound} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
        03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3458)
        03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3487)
        03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:119)
        03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at 

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1896)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-02 14:22:36.685: I/dalvikvm(233): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
    03-02 14:22:36.714: E/dalvikvm(233): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: How do we suppose to now what cause your crash? Provide log please..

Comment: "did not call through to super.onDestroy()" there's one issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
03-02 14:22:36.655: E/AndroidRuntime(233): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.troll.sound/com.troll.sound.Sound} did not call through to super.onDestroy()
```

Please call `super.onDestroy()` in your `onDestroy()` implementation.